# Does a Form describing JSON "Standard" exist?

Tags: json

I joined a project were we sell services for different providers through web, iOS and android apps. I am working on iOS. I was ask to display a purchase form via a web view and react by what is entered natively. I do so by intercepting the network communication but as you can imagine it is slow, error prone and just kind of stupid. 
I ask why it has to be done in this way, why I just cannot get the data and render the form myself natively, and I was told that soon also the android app will adapt this feature and as the form can slightly change for each providers that would be the easiest approach.

While I agree that it is easier to decide on the server which fields are needed for each call, I don't think that the logical conclusion is to request a html form and create hackish interception around it.

Before the implementation for android starts I want to propose another option:

Instead of rendering a website I want the server to create a JSON to describe the form, that than can easily be used at client-side to create the form. Basically a server generated view model.

My question is: is there some "standard" already how such a JSON should look like?

I imagine it something like this

```
{
  "form": {
    "action": {
      "action-name": "Send",
      "method": "POST",
      "target": "https://api.mydomain.com/purchase/"
    },
    "fieldsets": [{
      "fieldset-name": "personal information",
      "fields": [{
        "field": {
          "kind": "text-field",
          "field-name": "First Name",
          "validator": {
            "validator-name": "regex-validator",
            "arguments": [{
              "regex": ".{3:}"
            }]
          },
          "optional": false
        }
      }, {
        "field": {
          "kind": "text-field",
          "field-name": "Last Name",
          "validator": {
            "validator-name": "regex-validator",
            "arguments": [{
              "regex": ".{3:}"
            }]
          },
          "optional": false
        }
      }, {
        "field": {
          "kind": "text-field",
          "field-name": "Email",
          "validator": {
            "validator-name": "email-validator"
          },
          "optional": false
        }
      }, {
        "field": {
          "kind": "text-field",
          "field-name": "Confirm Email",
          "validator": {
            "validator-name": "email-validator"
          },
          "optional": false
        }
      }]
    }, {
      "fieldset-name": "Credit Card Data",
      "fields": [{
        "field": {
          "kind": "text-field",
          "field-name": "Credit Card Number",
          "validator": {
            "validator-name": "creditcard-number-validator"
          },
          "optional": false
        }
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: JSON doesn't really have a schema the way XML does, it is essentially a serialized object based on the class specification. At least it _should_ be, sometimes it is pieced together manually in code.

Answer (score 2):

I think the standard you are looking for is [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html). It's not specific to forms, it's a more general specification for defining what a particular JSON format looks like (like an XML schema). There are a few solutions for creating forms with JSON Schema, like [joshfire/jsonform](https://github.com/joshfire/jsonform).

Comment: I don't want to render a html site client side. I want to avoid html.

Comment: @vikingosegundo `is there some "standard" already how such a JSON should look like?` -- JSON Schema is that standard.  If you don't actually need to create forms, you could just look at joshfire/jsonform as an example of how JSON Schema would be applied to JSON representing a form.

Comment: Hey, my understanding of the (quite verbose) question is that the TO wants to know if there's a JSON-_based_ standard that describes _how forms_ (input elements like textareas and checkboxes) are layed out. vikingosegundo, please confirm that by clarifying/updating your question.

Comment: schemata are a way to define standards. I ask if there is something like a "standard"

Comment: @vikingosegundo the way the jsonform project handles this (and some other projects), the *schema actually defines the form*. There is not some other format that describes the form and the schema defines that format; the schema defines the form directly.